# Does dotenv override envvars set by docker compose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-dotenv

I'm not familiar with Docker or devops, but I have these files:

*.env.production*

```
DO_NOT_SEND_EMAILS=false
```

*docker-compose.ci.yml*

```
services:
  my-app:
    environment:
      - DO_NOT_SEND_EMAILS=true
```

- Both files contain more than that, but these are the relevant lines.
- What will the envvar be set to in the end?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like dotenv does not override variables if they are defined in the environment, [by design](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#why-is-it-not-overriding-existing-env-variables):

> By default, it won't overwrite existing environment variables as
>   dotenv assumes the deployment environment has more knowledge about
>   configuration than the application does. To overwrite existing
>   environment variables you can use Dotenv.overload.

So the answer probably depends on how you are using dotenv - `Dotenv.load` or `Dotenv.overload`.

Here is a minimal test:

#### `.env`

```
SOMEVAR=from .env file
ANOTHERVAR=also from .env file
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    build: .
    command: ruby test.rb
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    environment:
      SOMEVAR: from docker compose
```

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM dannyben/alpine-ruby
WORKDIR /app
RUN gem install dotenv
COPY . .
```

#### `test.rb`

```
require 'dotenv'

# values in .env will override
# Dotenv.overload

# values in .env will be used only if not already set in the environment
Dotenv.load

p ENV['SOMEVAR']
p ENV['ANOTHERVAR']
```

To run:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose run test
```

Answer (score 2):

As i know, it's not supposed to overwrite. Personally I use in docker env.

```
    env_file:
      - '.env.production'
```

instead of:

```
    environment:
      - DO_NOT_SEND_EMAILS=true
```

In this case always will rely on `.env.prod` file...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by DannyB `dotenv` doesn't override existing environment variables by default. For anyone using the `dotenv` CLI, you can override already existing environment variables using the `--override` or `-o` option like this:

```
dotenv -o -f ".env.local,.env"
```